# XHTML incompatibility with < asp:Menu> component using content-type="application/xhtml+xml"

Tags: javascript, asp.net, xhtml, menu, content-type

I´m using ASP.NET 4.0 and testing the ASP.NET XHTML compatibility with some components and have figured out that the server control < asp:Menu> doesn´t works properly with XHTML.

I want that the browser treat the page as XHTML and not as an HTML document (the default for html/text content-type). As only the latest browsers recognize this mode (IE only since version 9) I´m using content-type negotiation (see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479043.aspx#aspnetusstan_topic8) to deal properly when the browser supports it or not.

```
    void Application_PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Array.IndexOf(Request.AcceptTypes, "application/xhtml+xml") > -1)
        {
            Response.ContentType = "application/xhtml+xml";
        }
    }
```

That said, my application behaves accordingly, with the exception of the < asp:Menu> component, that don´t render properly.

I see that the problem is in the javascript generated by a WebResource.axd used to deal with the menu component.

Someone have faced a problem like it and figured out some workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't really offer much help, but I dislike how asp forces you into things like this. I wish there was more control over things like this.

Comment: I don't think there's much advantage to content-type negotiation. There are significant DOM differences in true-XHTML-mode which the vast majority of scripts aren't written to cope with, and it breaks caching in IE (unless you do it without setting the `Vary` header, in which case it breaks public caching).

Comment: @bobince Thanks for your comments. In fact, I have done some research about this issue and I realize that there are various differences between "real XHTML" pages served with mime-type "application/xhtml+xml" and an "markup compliant XHTML" page served with mime-type "text/html". In the former, the page is treated as a XML document and in the other don´t. There are differences in Javascript and DOM utilization too (see: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#compatGuidelines). ASP.NET 4.0 components could not be fully compatible with "real XHTML" pages (yet).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem itself was not resolved. To allow the site to be correctly rendered, I just continue to serve its pages as "html/text", removing the content-type negotiation.